# Django static path is not properly set

Tags: python, css, django

I am trying to learn `Django`,
In settings.py I have set:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/media'

MEDIA_URL = 'media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    '/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static',)
```

I have my css files in my

```
/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static/css/default.css
```

but when I try to access the webpage it doesnot load the css and gives Error.

```
"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8000/static/css/default.css"
```

I am new to this so I dont understand what is my root directory. what runs first and how Django tries to find the resources. If someone can guide me through this it would be great.

---

Guyz Guyz I was just doing hit and try and this happened. I renamed my `static` folder to `staticfiles` and then in `STATICFILES_DIRS` replaced the path from 
 `'/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static/',` to
 `'/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/staticfiles/',` and it worked. 
I have No Idea why. can someone please explain ?

output of `python manage.py runserver --traceback`

```
hussain@jarvis:~/django/ratingsite$ python manage.py runserver --traceback
Validating models...

0 errors found
December 08, 2013 - 01:48:39
Django version 1.5.4, using settings 'ratingsite.settings'
Development server is running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
[08/Dec/2013 01:48:41] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 930
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 38, in serve
    absolute_path = finders.find(normalized_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 238, in find
    for finder in get_finders():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 253, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 31, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 275, in _get_finder
    return Finder()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 62, in __init__
    "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
[08/Dec/2013 01:48:42] "GET /static/css/default.css HTTP/1.1" 500 59
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 73, in __call__
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
    return super(StaticFilesHandler, self).__call__(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 255, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 63, in get_response
    return self.serve(request)
    return self.serve(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 56, in serve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 56, in serve
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
    return serve(request, self.file_path(request.path), insecure=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 38, in serve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 38, in serve
    absolute_path = finders.find(normalized_path)
    absolute_path = finders.find(normalized_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 238, in find
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 238, in find
    for finder in get_finders():
    for finder in get_finders():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 253, in get_finders
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 253, in get_finders
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
    yield get_finder(finder_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 31, in wrapper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 31, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 275, in _get_finder
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 275, in _get_finder
    return Finder()
    return Finder()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 62, in __init__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 62, in __init__
    "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
    "The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should "
ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
```

Comment: The path specified in `STATICFILES_DIRS` is actually used as input location of static files, i.e the path from where files will be fetched to `STATIC_ROOT` when you run `collectstatic`. And in your case both of them are same.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary so where am I wrong ? why is it not working ?

Comment: What's the location of `default.css` on your system?

Comment: What version of Django are you using? This can vary greatly depending on the version.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary /home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static/css/default.css

Comment: Guyz Guyz I was just doing hit and try and this hapened. I renamed my static folder to `staticfiles` and then in `STATICFILES_DIRS` replaced the path from `    '/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static/',` to `    '/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/staticfiles/',` and it worked. I have No Idea why. can someone please explain ?

Comment: yeah, that's weird, what happens when you run `$ grep rin "staticfiles" *` on the whole project? 

Is this specified somewhere else? The django core devs might be interested if this is an actual bug.

Comment: @RobertJ. Nope, Nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes sense now.

The problem is this as is written in your stacktrace:

```
ImproperlyConfigured: The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting
```

And per your initial configuration:

```
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   '/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static',)
```

You will not that both of these point to **exactly the same directory**. This is not allowed for the reason described below.

The `ImproperlyConfigured` error was fixed when you changed the location of one of these configurations (so they were no longer identical).

The solution here is to:

- create a different `STATIC_ROOT` directory (we'd call this something like `/public/static/`) *do not put any files in this directory* this is where all of the static files are automatically collected to when your site is ready to publish.
- put the location/s of the files that you are developing in the `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

When you are ready to publish your project you are able to run `$ ./manage.py collectstatic` which will go through all the apps and staticfiles directories your project uses and compile a set of all the "final" static files you need in the `STATIC_ROOT` directory ready for publication with your finished site.

If your `STATIC_ROOT` directory was included in the directories that was gone through by `collectstatic` there would obviously be a recursive loop.

Comment: Thank you. You helped a lot. This is what I wanted for an Answer, an Explanation that why the heck is it not working. Thanks. can you please guide me to some good tutorial for all this things on Django. I tried to read the official tutorial and djnagobooks but its not very clear on issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following to your `urls.py`?

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Per the instructions here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/

---

Although you are getting a `500` error which suggests another problem.

What is the output of?:

```
$ python manage.py validate --traceback
```

Does this state some other kind of error?

---

How about the output of:

```
$ python manage.py shell

>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> print(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS)
```

---

As it is returning `500` rather than the expected `404` you could run:

```
$ python manage.py runserver --traceback
```

... and then see what the traceback history returns when you load the webpage.

Comment: Yes Did add the Static_URL and document_root, and `$ python manage.py validate --traceback` gives `0 errors found`

Comment: ('/home/hussain/django/ratingsite/ratingsite/static/',)

Comment: Can you confirm that you're still getting "`500 Internal Server Error`"? ... If there were a problem with your static settings this would should return a "`404`".

Comment: yes it is giving `"NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http://localhost:8000/static/css/default.css"`